# How to draw a different shape with straight lines and curved corners using Bezier paths in iOS

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation, uibezierpath, cgpath

I need to draw a shape with straight line and curves on corners using Bezier paths with CGPoints in an array. The CGPoints mentioned in array indicating corners of the shape. The path should be drawn at dynamically based on CGPoints (co-ordinates) in an array.

[Sample shape for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5dOE.png)

Comment: Initially I have created the CG mutable path for shape and then followed below links  to update curved corners on shape                                            1)https://github.com/Petrakeas/outlineDEMO    2)http://scaledinnovation.com/analytics/splines/aboutSplines.html

Comment: Is anyone having a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

To draw a polygon

```
   //// General Declarations
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//// Polygon Drawing
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 33.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 226.5);
CGContextRotateCTM(context, -90 * M_PI / 180);

UIBezierPath* polygonPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[polygonPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(99.5, 0)];
[polygonPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(185.67, 47.75)];
[polygonPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(185.67, 143.25)];
[polygonPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(99.5, 191)];
[polygonPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(13.33, 143.25)];
[polygonPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(13.33, 47.75)];
[polygonPath closePath];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[polygonPath fill];

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

put this in the drawRect method of your uiview:

THis gives the image:

[image]

Curved polygon:

```
//// Bezier Drawing
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 59.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 126.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 55.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 116.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 59.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 105.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 91.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 55.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 101.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 44.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 91.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 55.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 96.75, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 48.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 113.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 39.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 106.25, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 40.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 113.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 39.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 188.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 39.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 203.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 44.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 188.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 39.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 198, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 40.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 213.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 55.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 209, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 48.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 213.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 55.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 245.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 105.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 249.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 116.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 245.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 126.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 213.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 173.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 203.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 180.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 213.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 173.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 209, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 177.25)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 188.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 183.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 198, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 183.75) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 188.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 183.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 113.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 183.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 101.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 180.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 113.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 183.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 106.25, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 183.75)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 94.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 173.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 96.75, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 177.25) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 94.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 173.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 59.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 126.5)];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[bezierPath fill];
[UIColor.grayColor setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
[bezierPath stroke];
```

[image]

To produce result similar to your image:

```
//// Bezier Drawing
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 57.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 126.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 55.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 116.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 57.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 105.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 73.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 55.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 78.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 44.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 73.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 55.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 76.12, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 48.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 84.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 39.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 80.88, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 40.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 84.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 39.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 122, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 39.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 129.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 44.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 122, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 39.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 126.75, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 40.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 134.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 55.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 132.25, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 48.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 134.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 55.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 150.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 105.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 152.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 116.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 150.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 126.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 134.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 173.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 129.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 180.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 134.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 173.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 132.25, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 177.25)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 122, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 183.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 126.75, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 183.75) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 122, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 183.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 84.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 183.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 78.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 180.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 84.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 183.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 80.88, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 183.75)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 75, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 173.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 76.12, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 177.25) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 75, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 173.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 57.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 126.5)];
[UIColor.grayColor setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
[bezierPath stroke];
```

[image]

Comment: what is that condiiton?

Comment: I want to add one more condition to above problem that is I have CGPoints in an array which will be used for create shape with Bezier path. The path should be drawn at dynamically based on CGPoints(co-ordinates) in array

Comment: Hi Mr.T, Do you have solution for above problem?

Comment: how do u store the points in an array ? r u considering the bezier path for only one screen size ?

Comment: float x = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
     float y = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height;

Comment: NSArray *shapeCooridnates = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
     [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake((100.00/375)*x,(175.00/667)*y, 0, 0)],
     [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake((150.00/375)*x,(75.00/667)*y, 0, 0)],
     [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake((200.00/375)*x,(75.00/667)*y, 0, 0)],
     [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake((250.00/375)*x,(175.00/667)*y, 0, 0)],
     [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake((200.00/375)*x,(275.00/667)*y, 0, 0)],
     [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake((150.00/375)*x,(275.00/667)*y, 0, 0)], nil];

Comment: what device screens are you targeting ?

Comment: We consider bezier path for all screens

Comment: Hi Mr.T,  I appreciate your valuable support to resolve my issue

Comment: provide me the exact bezier path you need to draw or the image

Comment: I already gave exact Bezier path  CGPoints and image for your reference. You can refer that one

Comment: do u want to draw that polygon ?

Comment: Yes I need that polygon

Comment: The above one is not correct. I need curved corners on shape. You can refer below link for correct shape.                 http://i.stack.imgur.com/t5dOE.png

Comment: Now the above one is correct. But You were drawn that image with some static points. I need the same image based on array points dynamically

Comment: I need some common function for different images

Comment: it depends on view size.....you can scale this bezier path to fit the diferent sizes, you dont need an array

Comment: Yes, You are correct. But I need a common function for different polygon shapes

Comment: i.e Different polygon shapes - pentagon, hexagon

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96417/discussion-on-answer-by-mr-t-how-to-draw-a-different-shape-with-straight-lines-a).